# unitary representation of semisimple lie groups in view of Moore's ergodicity thm

Tags: lie-groups

Let $G=G_1\times\ldots\times G_n$ be a product of (connected) simple Lie groups and $(H, \pi)$ be a unitary representation of $G$. In a proof of Moore's ergodicity thm it uses the following fact $$\pi=\oplus_{I\subset [1,\ldots, n]} \pi_I
$$
where $(\pi_I, H_I)$ be the subrepresentation of $\pi$ whose kernel contains 
$G_i$ for $i\in I$ but no $G_j$ for $j\not \in I$.

How do we prove this fact?

Comment: I think I should give a ref. for this.
Ergodic theory and topological dynamics of group actions on homogeneous spaces, M Bekka & M Mayer, Cambridge University Press, P91.
In fact, I don't quite believe this fact.

Comment: One thing that IS true is that $\pi$ factors into an external tensor product of (unitary) representations $\pi_i$ of $G_i$ (this is Type I-ness of semisimple Lie groups). You can see if the proof can be adapted to this decomposition.

Answer (score 3):

There is indeed a slight problem on p.91 of Bekka-Mayer, as they state that ${\cal H}_{\pi_I}$ is ``the subspace of vectors which are fixed by all $G_i,\;i\in I$, but not by any of the others.''

This condition clearly does not define a linear subspace. That problem may be overcome as follows: let $\pi=\int^\oplus_X \rho_x d\mu(x)$ be a direct integral decomposition of $\pi$ into irreducible representations $\rho_x$, over some measure space $(X,\mu)$. Since simple Lie groups are type I, we may write $\rho_x=\rho_{1,x}\otimes...\otimes \rho_{n,x}$, where $\rho_{i,x}$ is an irreducible representation of $G_i$. For $I\subset\{1,...,n\}$, define a subset $X_I$ of $X$, as the set of $x$'s in $X$ such that $\rho_{i,x}$ is trivial for $i\in I$, and non-trivial for $i\notin I$. Then the $X_I$'s, for $I$ running over all subsets of $\{1,...,n\}$, is a measurable partition of $X$; defining $\pi_I=:\int^\oplus_{X_I}\rho_x d\mu(x)$, we get $\pi=\bigoplus_I \pi_I$ as desired.